# How to change Menu indicator color in activity ToolBar

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I want to change menu  indicator color in activity ToolBar, Now its color is not white or it has alpha option, I want to be White

[image]

I am using AppCompatActivity and here is my toolbar xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom overflow icon with white color and apply that icon in your theme style like this

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
      <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverFlow</item>     
</style>

<style name="CustomOverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_custom_icon</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the colorControlNormal attribute.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```